# Can the 2009 Mac mini work with its optical drive removed?

Tags: mac, mac-mini, optical-drive

I wonder if the Mac mini 2009 needs the optical drive for work, or if I can just remove it?

I don't need it at all and have an external drive just in case. I will replace the HDD with an SSD and want to keep the Mac cool and lower the energy consumption as much as possible.

Comment: Just a note that if you have the Apple external drive, it will not work with a Mac which "already has" an internal drive.  I think this limitation holds true, even if the internal drive is broken or removed.

Comment: Thanks. Just for the record: I now have the Mac mini 2009 and it's so quiet and uses so few power, that I'm perfectly happy with it, even with the DVD drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. Many have swapped out their internal DVD-ROMs on favor of installing another bay that can handle an HDD/SSD.

Here's an example of an optical to HDD bay: http://www.ifixit.com/Apple-Parts/12-7-mm-SATA-Optical-Bay-SATA-Hard-Drive-Enclosure/IF107-081